# Describe a recursive algorithm to print all N-Digit binary strings that do not have any consecutive 1s

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary

I found a solution that gives consecutive 1s but I cannot find anything that does not include consecutive 1s in the binary string, can someone help me out?

Comment: At every level of recursion, you have two options, add a `0` to the string, or add `10` to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way (in pseudo-code that happens to be valid Python):

```
def gen(n):
  if n == 0:
    yield ''
    return
  for s in gen(n-1):
    yield s + '0'
    if s == '' or s[-1] == '0':
      yield s + '1'

for s in gen(5):
  print(s)
```

It generates all strings of length `n-1` and then:

- appends a `0` to form a valid string of length `n`;
- appends a `1`, but only if it won't violate the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple one.

```
def f(n, result=""):
    if n==0:
        print(result)
        return

    if len(result) == 0 or result[-1]=="0":
        f(n-1, result+"1")
    f(n-1, result+"0")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a recursive algorithm, I am thinking having a recursive function that adds `'0'` or `'1'` to a string, depending on the last character of string.

My solution below calls recursion until the string's length reaches the given `n`. Its recursive calls are made 1) by adding `'0'` to the string and 2) by adding `'1'` to the string if the previous character is not `'1'`. Appending `'1'` only when previous character is not `'1'` would prevent the string to contain consecutive `'1'`s. The worst case time complexity would be **O(2^n)** due to two recursive calls, and the space complexity would be **O(n)** since recursion depth will be n.

```
void printNDigitBinaries(int n) {
    printBinHelper(n, "");
}

void printBinHelper(int n, String s) {
    if (s.length() == n) {
        System.out.println(s);
        return;
    }

    printBinHelper(n, s+"0");
    if (s.length() == 0 || s.charAt(s.length()-1) != '1') printBinHelper(n, s+"1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recurse from an empty string. At every call, make decision on what to append on what is the last character in the base string. Terminate when the string achieves the required size.

```py
    def recurse(base,n):
        #termination criteria
        if len(base)==n:`
            print(base)
    
        #You can add '0' or '1' if the base string ends with '0' or is empty  
        #and recurse. There is no issue having consecutive zeroes.
    
        elif base== "" or base[-1]=="0" :
            recurse(base+"0",n)
            recurse(base+"1",n)
      
        #To prevent consecutive '1's, append '0' only to the base string ending 
        #with '0'
    
        elif base[-1]=="1":
            recurse(base+"0",n)
    n=int(input())
    recurse("",n)
```

For n=5, the output is:

> 00000 00001 00010 00100 00101 01000 01001 01010 10000 10001 10010 10100 10101